# How to show nonlinear Schrodinger equation is an infinite dimensional Hamiltonian system?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hamilton-equations

The nonlinear Schrodinger equation is 
$$
ih\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} = -\frac{h^2}{2}\Delta \psi + V\psi-|\psi|^{p-1}\psi
$$
From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_system), I know the Hamiltonian system is

> > > [image]

And from [**Stability of semiclassical bound states of nonlinear Schrödinger equations with potentials**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01218621), the author say the nonlinear Schrodinger equation (NLS) is Hamiltonian system. But for the given $E(\phi)$ , what is $p$ and $q$ as in definition of Hamiltonian system?

> > > [image]

Answer (score 1):

Define the Hamiltonian density functional $\mathcal{H}$ as
$$
\mathcal{H}=\frac{\hbar^2}{2}\nabla\Psi\cdot\nabla\Psi^*+(V-|\Psi|^p)\Psi^*\Psi.
$$
The evolution equation is given by
$$
i\hbar\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial t}=\frac{\delta\mathcal{H}}{\delta\Psi^*}=\{\Psi,\mathcal{H}\},
$$
where the commutator between two functionals $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ is given by
$$
\{\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}\}=\frac{\delta\mathcal{F}}{\delta\Psi}\frac{\delta\mathcal{G}}{\delta\Psi^*}-\frac{\delta\mathcal{F}}{\delta\Psi^*}\frac{\delta\mathcal{G}}{\delta\Psi},
$$
with $\frac{\delta\mathcal{F}}{\delta\Psi}$ being  the [functional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative). The canonical pair analogous to $(q,p)$ is given here by $(\Psi,\Psi^*)$.